# Using Node.js with Django and Backbone.js

Tags: django, web-applications, node.js, backbone.js

**Some background:** I am planning to build an application with Django as the backend and using Backbone.js as the frontend Javascript framework. It is a Single page application (SPA) and this is the reason I decided to use Backbone.js. The application is similar to a blogging engine; users post entries containing text and images and are able to view them by "tag". They can search through their entries by "tag" or by a particular word.

Lately, after hearing about all the fuss about Node.js, I am wondering how it can help my application. But I don't want to make the app run purely on node.js on the backend, i.e., I still wish to use Django for the backend. Would it be possible to use Node for the "middle end" as mentioned [here](http://blog.getify.com/2010/07/why-node-js-rocks-the-middle-end/)?

How can I optimize my app with Node.js?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It sounds like your application does not necessarily need Node.js. The main reasons you might want to use Node in addition to a more traditional framework like Django or Rails is if there is a real time or multiplayer aspect to your application.

I wouldn't use Node.js because there is a lot of *fuss about it* - if you need the aforementioned functionality, though, it can be great.

A high level architecture of your application might look something like:

**Django**

- Serving your single page
- Serving assets(css, js, images, etc...)
- Handling DB connection - best to setup RESTful routes for each data model
- Data processing, etc...

**Backbone**

- Handling user interaction
- Make http requests to read and write data

**Node (Optional)**

- Use something like [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) to notify clients of updates (instead of poling)
- You can **replace the functionality of Django** with one or a combination of node modules

Comment: >  best to setup RESTful routes for each data model

Or you may use Tastypie.

Answer (score 4):

If you feel comfortable with python and Django in general, I'd recommend using a web server like Tornado. It is very easy to use and has a steep learning curve if you're familiar with Django. In general, you'll see performance improvements and you'll have the ability to implement otherwise "obscure" functionality, like Comet programming.

As for the frontend, yes, Backbone is an excellent choice, but keep an eye on Coffeescript too...

Comment: well, it's obscure :) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/what-is-meant-by-steep-learning-curve